# How to filter by one-to-many property having only one of its values be a particular value

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a filter like the following:

```
Object.query.filter(
  Object.child_id == Child.id, 
  Child.grandchild_id == 12
).all()
```

The intention is to return all Objects who are the grandparent of grandchild 12. Obviously this is a contrived example.

However, this will return an empty list if Object has more than one grandchild, because not all grandchildren will have the id 12. So how do I filter such that it requires that *one* of the grandchildren have the id 12, but not all of them?

More complex example closer to the code I'm working with:

```
    A.query.filter(
        A.x == 1,
        B.A_id == A.id,
        B.y == True,
        B.C_id == C.id,
        C.z == some_passed_in_z,
    ).distinct(A.id)

# Relevant relationships are defined in B.
class B:
    A_id = DB.Column(
        DB.Integer,
        DB.ForeignKey("A_table.id"),
        nullable=False,
    )
    C_id = DB.Column(
        DB.Integer,
        DB.ForeignKey("c_table.id"),
        nullable=False,
    )
    y = DB.Column(
        DB.Boolean,
        nullable=False,
        default=False,
        index=True,
    )
```

**First of all**, I want to know that I'm correct that `C.z == some_passed_in_z` only returns `A` instances that are related to a `B` instance who's related `C` instances *all* have `some_passed_in_z` as their `z` values. **Is that correct?**

Second of all, I've tried deleting `C.z == some_passed_in_z` from the filter, and the data I want is then returned, however it obvious doesn't then filter out anything by its z value. So I want to know how to produce a filter like this:

```
    A.query.filter(
        A.x == 1,
        B.A_id == A.id,
        B.y == True,
        B.C_id == C.id,
        B.c_instances[any].z == some_passed_in_z,
    ).distinct(A.id)
```

Where `B.c_instances[any].z == some_passed_in_z` means that that filter passes if any C connected to a particular B instance has a `z` value of `some_passed_in_z`.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your problem, however to filter `Child` model you need to `join` or `outerjoin` it ```Object.query.join(Child).filter(
  Object.child_id == Child.id, 
  Child.grandchild_id == 12
).all()```

Comment: @jorzel Hmm, that join doesn't seem to solve my problem. My problem is that I think `Child.grandchild_id == 12` is requiring that all "grandchild" objects of "Child" have the id 12. Is that correct? I want to require only that *one* of the grandchild objects has that id. I tried outerjoin and normal join in various combinations. None gave me the result I need.

Comment: I still dont understand. Could you provide your models setup (models definition), maybe some examples of records in a db and what is your expected result on that dataset?

Comment: @jorzel I've elaborated in the question.

Comment: You may find `.has()` and/or `.any()` helpful. Details in [the tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#exists-forms-has-any).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. My problem was that I was misunderstanding how SqlAlchemy treated the filters. What its doing is just a join (which may end up with multiple duplicate records of the base object), and so really the `C.z == some_passed_in_z` is *already* doing what I wanted. This was just a red herring.

What was really tripping me up was that the real equivalent in our code of `B.y == True` (which was actually `B.y in ("some", "list", "of", "values")` was missing a value needed to select one of the B rows.

Thanks for trying to help jorzel!